# R Markdown: Set Font Size for the Title

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am using R Markdown to create a word document, and trying to increase the font size of the title and author on the cover page.  Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a reference Word doc as a parameter in the YAML frontmatter and the styles in the knitted document will be based on them, then:

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: mystyles.docx
---
```